# Wordpress: Get pll_the_languages inside my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

How can i get languages into my custom plugin of wordpress?
When i call pll_the_languages() it's output me error.
Maybe i should call some global method?

[image]

My plugin code:

```
/**
 * woocommerce-admin-ajax
 *
 * @package           woocommerce-admin-ajax
 * @author            Sergey Samokhvalov
 * @wordpress-plugin
 *
 * Plugin Name:       WooCommerce Admin Ajax
 * Plugin URI:        https://redirex.studio
 * Description:       Additional functionality for ajax update of product in admin page without reload page.
 * Version:           1.0
 * Requires PHP:      5.6.20
 * Author:            Sergey Samokhvalov
 * Author URI:        https://github.com/RedirexStudio/woocommerce-admin-ajax
 * Text Domain:       Woocommerce Admin Ajax
 */
/* Registrate admin js and styles */

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'reg_amin_js' );
function reg_amin_js( $page ) {
  // change to the $page where you want to enqueue the script
  if( $page == 'post-new.php' || $page == 'post.php' || $page == 'edit.php' ) {
    // Enqueue WordPress media scripts
    wp_enqueue_media();
    
    // Enqueue custom script that will interact with wp.media
    wp_enqueue_script( 'woocommerce_admin-scripts', plugins_url('/admin/js/admin.js',__FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    // Enqueue custom styles for admin panel
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_admin-styles', plugins_url('/admin/css/style.css', __FILE__ ));
    
  }
}
/* //END//Registrate admin js and styles */



/* Polylang capability */
pll_the_languages();
/* //END//Polylang capability */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved.
You should use admin_init action:

```
    function plugin_pll_register_string() {
        if ( function_exists( 'pll_register_string' ) ) {
      pll_register_string('woocommerce-admin-ajax-strings', 'Update');
      pll_register_string('woocommerce-admin-ajax-strings', 'Published');
      pll_register_string('woocommerce-admin-ajax-strings', 'Product is updated!');
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'plugin_pll_register_string' );
```